# Django @staticmethod sum of two fields

Tags: python, django

I have a quick question. I'm trying to add a field to a model which is the sum of 2 fields.

For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
      fee = models.DecimalField()
      fee_gst = models.DecimalField()
```

I thought I could just add a @staticmethod inside the model:

```
@staticmethod
def fee_total(self):
     return self.fee + self.fee_gst
```

But I can't seem to access the "fee_total" field of the model using:

```
model = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
total = model.fee_total
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried _total = model.fee_total()_ note missing '()' in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to add a method to your model so this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods might help you.

`@staticmethod` is a decorator that declares method to the `class`, so whats the difference?

Well long story short, static methods don't have instances to any particular object just an instance to the `class` Object, what do I mean by `class` object, most things in python like functions, class, and of course instances of objects are actually objects ...

Like everyone has mentioned before `@property` is a decorator that lets a method act as variable ... so you don't have to explicitly use `()`

eitherway, you would want to do this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    fee = models.DecimalField()
    fee_gst = models.DecimalField()

    @property        
    def fee_total(self):
        return self.fee + self.fee_gst
```

though the docs take a longer approach:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    fee = models.DecimalField()
    fee_gst = models.DecimalField()


    def _fee_total(self):
        return self.fee + self.fee_gst
    fee_total = property(_fee_total)
```

both methods are pretty much equivalent though we use the decorator as a short-hand.

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for all your replies guys, this one was the most clear.. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

From the way your interacting with your model instance, I believe you actually want to use the [@property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) decorator instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this with passing the instance as parameter as below.

```
 total = model.fee_total(model)
```

The static method does not pass implicit `self` as instance parameter.

However, as 'Filip Dupanović' suggested you may want to use @property instead of @staticmethod